# Detect test failure in testng @AfterMethod

Tags: java, testng

I want to take a screenshot if a test fails. Rather than wrapping all test methods with try/catch blocks, I would like to add this logic to the method annotated with `@AfterMethod`.

How can I detect in the method annotated with `@AfterMethod` if the current test has failed?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the method annotated with `@AfterMethod` has an `ITestResult` parameter then TestNG will automatically inject the result of the test. (source: [TestNG documentation, section 5.18.1](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection))

This should do the job:

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
   if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
      //your screenshooting code goes here
   }        
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A good option is to use an `ITestListener` instead of handling failure reporting in `@AfterMethod`.  The test listener's `onTestFailed()` function will be called after your test method has run, but before the `@AfterMethod` method has run. (Note that there is not an `onTestFinished()` function in the listener; that role is fulfilled by `@AfterMethod`.)

To make things easier on yourself, you can use a `TestListenerAdapter`, which will implement all of the other functions that you don't specifically `@Override` yourself.

What you end up with is:

```
public class MyTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result){
    yourTakeScreenShotFunctionHere();
   }
}
```

You then attach the listener to your test class with

```
@Listeners({MyTestListener.class})
public class MyTestClass(){etc}
```

The `ITestResult` is a reference to your test class's object, so you can use reflection to grab data out of it such as a Selenium WebDriver instance, etc.

You can have as many different listeners as you want, to do various things such as clean up or preserve error logs, take screenshots, trigger other reporting functionality, send emails, or whatever you want.

Comment: Why do you think this approach is better than @AfterMethod ?

Comment: It's better because it will apply to all the tests in a suite, no matter where they are defined

Answer (score 2):

Variant to the previous answers:

Since you already know that you want to take the screenshot only in case of failure, you can use `onTestFailure()` method from `TestListenerAdapter`:

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;

public class LFailure extends TestListenerAdapter {

@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
    System.out.println("Failure");
    // your screenshot code
    }
}
```

PS: don't forget to add `LFailure` to your testng.xml, or directly in the code like this:

```
@Listeners({ LFailure.class })
```

(preferably in a base class, from which all your tests inherit)

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you can implement a listener [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html) and implement the `afterInvocation()` method.  This gives you access to the result object of your method.  You can put your code to take a screenshot here.